# OpenLayers Map Projections with Proj4JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, openlayers, gis, proj4js

I am trying to overlay data about the Chesapeake Bay Watershed over an OpenLayers map.  The problem is, no matter how I try to project the data, the watershed (drawn with d3) is not in the correct position.  The code I'm using to zoom to the watershed is here:

```
zoomToWatershed: function() {
  // Remove any svg currently on the map
  CP.MapFunctions.reset();
  // Fetch data from Flask
  CP.RequestHandler.get(
     "/get_data/watershed_topo", 
     function(json) {  
        ws = JSON.parse(json);
        watershed_coords = ws.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];
        CP.map.setCenter(CP.cumberland, CP.watershed_zoom);
        watershed_coords.forEach(function(pair) {
           // Transform from NAD83 to Web Mercator
           var t = proj4(proj4.defs["EPSG:4269"], proj4.defs["SR-ORG:7483"], pair);
           // Get the pixel values
           px = CP.map.getViewPortPxFromLonLat(
              new OpenLayers.LonLat(t[0], t[1])
              );
           pair[0] = px.x;
           pair[1] = px.y;
        });
        // console.log(watershed_coords);
        CP.canvas.append("path")
           .datum(watershed_coords)
           .attr("d", d3.svg.line())
           .attr("class", "watershed");
     }
  );
}
```

The shape file that I am using for the watershed had no .prj file, but the metadata on the ftp server said that the projection used was NAD83 (EPSG4269), hence the conversion.  SR-ORG:7483 is the equivalent of EPSG:900913, or the web-standard cartographic projection.

The Proj4js parts are defined in a separate js file like so:

```
proj4.defs["EPSG:4269"] = "+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +no_defs"; 
proj4.defs["SR-ORG:6864"] = "+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=637813 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";
proj4.defs["SR-ORG:7483"] = "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs";
```

My question is: where am I going wrong?  I have tested both web-standard cartographic projections (i.e. EPSG:900913 and EPSG:3857, which I'm pretty sure are actually the same thing), as well as the standard EPSG:4326.

Comment: 900913 and 3857 are the same thing. What projection is your base map in?

Comment: Any chance of either a small example in jsFiddle or an example of your json, because at the moment it is a bit hard to visualize your problem?